# How to customise web-notifications?

Tags: javascript, html, web-notifications

I want to send web-notifications with my own input and decide when I send it (e.g. submitting a form). I'm making this for non-coding experienced people, so I'm looking for a simple interface

I'm trying to make a web notifications system from a form. This way I can decide when and what message the notification will be displaying. My current code is not working:

(Note: I have already asked for permission to display notifications!)

Form

```
<form id='form' >
<label for='userInput' class='alert-title'>Notifications</label><br>
<div class='lijn3'></div>
<label for='userInput'>Make a new notification</label><br>
<label for='userInput'>Title</label><br>
<input  type='text' id='userInput' /><br>
  <label for='userText'>Text</label><br>
 <input  type='text' id='userText' /><br>
  <input  type='submit' onclick='createNotification();' />
</form>

<script>
function createNotification() {
    var title = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("userText").value;
    var image = '/style/afbeeldingen/profielfoto.png';
    console.log(title,text)
    var no = new Notification(title, { body: text, icon: img });
}
</script>
```

When I submit the form, I don't get a notification. Instead, it is refreshing the page.
What is wrong in my code or how should I approach this? Any working (alternative, maybe without a form?) solution is welcome!

This is my first question. Please tell me if you don't understand the question or correct me:)

Comment: Are you using localhost, http or https? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using https en chrome

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable form submit. The quicker way to handle this would be change this line:

```
<input  type='submit' onclick='createNotification();' />
```

To this:

```
<input  type='button' onclick='createNotification();' />
```

Snippet:

```js
function createNotification() {
    var title = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("userText").value;
    var image = '/style/afbeeldingen/profielfoto.png';
    console.log(title,text)
    var no = new Notification(title, { body: text, icon: image });
}
```

```html
<form id='form' >
<label for='userInput' class='alert-title'>Notifications</label><br>
<div class='lijn3'></div>
<label for='userInput'>Make a new notification</label><br>
<label for='userInput'>Title</label><br>
<input  type='text' id='userInput' /><br>
  <label for='userText'>Text</label><br>
 <input  type='text' id='userText' /><br>
  <input  type='button' onclick='createNotification();' />
</form>
```

Plus:
you need to change `img` to `image` as your variable name. So this: `var no = new Notification(title, { body: text, icon: img });` Should be this: `var no = new Notification(title, { body: text, icon: image });`

Comment: The console.log is now working, but I don't get a notification and there's no error message

Comment: I can't tell with the given code. MDN got very informative page with examples and use case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: I switched to onesignal for now, it's easy to implement. But i will read the page and hopefully come up with a solution. Thank you for the help!